# Can you identify the car make/model of this car?

Tags: tail-lights, vehicle-identification

This car hit our vehicle and drove away last night, leaving its shattered passenger-side tail light behind. Any ideas on what make/model the car is from these photos? I'm guessing 2014-ish Toyota Corolla, but I'm not the most knowledgable car person. Thanks for any tips.[image][image] [image]

Comment: It would help to include your country.

Comment: I agree that it looks like a 2014 - 2019 Toyota Corolla. The tail lights are definitely Corolla lights and look like 2014 - 2016, but are very similar to 2017 - 2019 as well, so hard to say. Beyond that, I don't think the pictures are clear enough to tell much. :/

Comment: Are there any molded in numbers on those broken parts? Often those code numbers identify make, model and yr.